# Determination of missing codec (Phonon)

Tags: qt, codec, phonon

How to determine which codec is missing when play back audio/video via Phonon?
If you know please help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [isMimeTypeAvailable](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/phonon-backendcapabilities.html#isMimeTypeAvailable) to check what Phonon is saying it's capable of decoding.